# Unable to open document on DocuSign sent via on behalf

Tags: docusignapi, send-on-behalf-of

i am using DocuSign .Net Client to send documents.

Simple scenario of sending is working fine - recipient receives sent documents, and i can open them from DocuSign Manage tab.

But the problem when i am trying to send document on behalf with some other email as sender - document is sent to recipient fine (with correct sender email), but i can not **open** (and even see) this document and letter in DocuSign Manage tab.

(In the reports tab it is displayed, but different as other ones - it has no link to open)

**Question** : Is this behavior normal, or i have just made mistakes in API calls, or Account settings?

P.S. - All permission configuration in both DocuSign Accounts configured properly. All screenshots attached.

Manage tab: http://screencast.com/t/tOPAkXzwB

Reports tab: http://screencast.com/t/HGfGZZLg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] in the relevant code as text in your post.  External links are no substitute for code in the post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the DocuSign Webapp you do not have access (admin or not) to any users envelopes until you share those users to yourself. Sharing instructions can be found [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-user-sharing-settings). That will allow you to open and view the envelope when you are not the actual sender.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! That was hard to find that this section is important for open sent documents.